# Errno 22 Invalid Argument Python

Tags: python, file, shutil, file-copying

I'm trying to copy one file's content to another, and error appears, what do i do wrong?

```py
for file in os.listdir('offer'):
    if '.css' in file:
        print(file)
        with open(f'offer/{file}', 'r+') as f:
            with open('offer/id.css', 'w+') as style_file:
                shutil.copyfile(f'offer/{f}', f'offer/{style_file}')
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Katerina/Desktop/python/test_attempt.py", line 50, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile(f'offer/{f}', f'offer/{style_file}')
  File "C:\Users\Katerina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "offer/<_io.TextIOWrapper name='offer/id.css' mode='r+' encoding='cp1251'>"
```

Comment: You're passing the file handler into the string formatter. Not *too* sure why the files need to be opened... just pass `offer/{file}` and `offer/id.css` as args to copyfile?

Comment: `shutil.copyfile` simply replaces a named file with another; it accepts file names, not open file handles, as arguments.

Comment: tried to remove with open, and now my needed file saves only last file's in for cycle data, but i need to catch em all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like

```
with open('offer/id.css', 'w') as style_file:
    for file in os.listdir('offer'):
        if '.css' in file:
            #print(file)
            with open(f'offer/{file}', 'r+') as f:
                for line in f:
                    style_file.write(line)
```

The purpose of `shutil.copyfile` is different; it doesn't really allow you to access or modify the contents of either file, it just copies one to the other.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was not your problem, but when I got the generic `[Errno 22] Invalid Argument` error when running `shutil.copy`, the problem was the permissions for the destination folder for the app account had changed. I just needed to restore `Write Permissions` for the folder to the account that the app was running on.